# MySQL count left join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

So here is my query

```
SELECT 
    `ez_cell_ar_report`.`custno`,
    `ez_cell_ar_report`.`company`,
    count(net10sold.custno) as Net10_Sims_Sold,
    count(net10used.custno) as Net10_Sims_Used,
    (count(net10sold.custno) - count(net10used.custno)) as Net10_Sims_OnHand
from
    `ez_cell_ar_report`
LEFT join
    (select `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`custno` from `ez_cell_detail_sales` 
        where `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10SIM'
        or `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10SIMIS'
        or `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10NANOSIM'
        or `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10NANOSIMIS'
        or `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10SIMDUAL'
        OR `ez_cell_detail_sales`.`item` = 'NET10SIMFREE'
        )
        AS net10sold
    on net10sold.custno = `ez_cell_ar_report`.`custno`
LEFT JOIN
    ((select `activations_view`.`custno` from `activations_view` 
        inner join
            `net10_activations_view`
        on `activations_view`.`serial` = `net10_activations_view`.`sim`)
    union all (select `net10_simswap_view`.`custno` from `net10_simswap_view`
                where `net10_simswap_view`.`custno` is not null
        )) net10used
on net10used.custno = `ez_cell_ar_report`.`custno`
where

    `ez_cell_ar_report`.`state` IN ('MI','AL','AR','AZ','CA','CO','CT','DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','IA','ID','IL','IN')
    group by `ez_cell_ar_report`.`custno`,`ez_cell_ar_report`.`company`
```

My problem is that Net10_Sims_Sold is always the same as Net10_Sims_Used it should be different it should be a count of all the records that match the custno from the union all query. Can someone please help?

Comment: `COUNT()` does not include null values. You will have to convert the nulls to something else (blank or zero perhaps) in the sub-`SELECT`.

Comment: Also, you can temporarily remove the `group by` line (and the outermost `COUNT()` functions) to see what is being returned and thus aid in debugging.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a SQLFiddle with the tables you reference and a few rows of meaningful data in each one so we can test our attempts. This query is somewhat involved.